# Merge Sort with an integer list (positive & negative numbers) C#

Tags: c#, mergesort

I'm trying to sort a list with both negative and positive numbers using a merge sort for a project I'm working on. I've created two subroutines; MSort and Merge. I'm using Merge Sort in itself as that's a required algorithm for my project. I'm trying to sort the numbers from smallest to largest but I've encountered a problem. The count of the list eventually comes to 0 and is stuck in a loop forever.

When creating the merge sort algorithm; I'm using this as a reference:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/a-simple-merge-sort-implementation-c-sharp

Thanks

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> test = new List<int>();

            List<int> answer = new List<int>();

            test.Add(1);
            test.Add(6);
            test.Add(-2);
            test.Add(323);
            test.Add(32);
            test.Add(-32);
            test.Add(23);
            test.Add(3);
            test.Add(123);
            test.Add(5);

            answer = MSort(test);

            Console.WriteLine(answer);
        }
        public static List<int> MSort(List<int> points)
        {
            List<int> left, right;
            List<int> result = new List<int>(points.Count);

            if (points.Count <= -1) { return points; }

            int midpoint = points.Count / 2;

            left = new List<int>(midpoint);

            if ((points.Count % 2) == 0)
            {
                right = new List<int>(midpoint);
            }
            else { right = new List<int>(midpoint + 1); }

            for (int i = 0; i < midpoint; i++)
            {
                left.Add(points[i]);
                left[i] = points[i];
            }

            int temp = 0;

            for (int j = midpoint; j < points.Count; j++)
            {
                right.Add(points[j]);
                right[temp] = points[j];
            }

            left = MSort(left);
            right = MSort(right);

            return result = Merge(left, right);

        }

        public static List<int> Merge(List<int> left, List<int> right)
        {
            int length = left.Count + right.Count;

            List<int> result = new List<int>(length);

            int leftIndex, rightIndex, resultIndex;
            leftIndex = rightIndex = resultIndex = 0;

            while ((leftIndex < left.Count) || (rightIndex < right.Count))
            {
                if ((leftIndex < left.Count) && (rightIndex < right.Count))
                {
                    if (left[leftIndex] <= right[rightIndex])
                    {
                        result[resultIndex] = left[leftIndex];
                        leftIndex++;
                        resultIndex++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result[resultIndex] = right[rightIndex];
                        rightIndex++;
                        resultIndex++;
                    }
                }
                else if (leftIndex < left.Count)
                {
                    result[resultIndex] = left[leftIndex];
                    leftIndex++;
                    resultIndex++;
                }
                else if (rightIndex < right.Count)
                {
                    result[resultIndex] = right[rightIndex];
                    rightIndex++;
                    resultIndex++;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

For MSort, points.count eventually goes to 0, and I have no ideas why.

Comment: Minor point: `if (points.Count <= -1) { return points; }` - don't you mean zero (or actually one) here? --- More importantly: `left.Add(points[i]); left[i] = points[i];` - don't do the second statement, the first is enough. Same with right, of course.

Comment: `if (points.Count <= -1) { return points; }` This can never be true as the `Count` of an enumeration can never get negative. And this may also be the reason why your algorithm never stops, because the stop condition cannot be met

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Actually, your first point isn't so "minor" after all, because it's the only condition stopping the recursion. But as it cannot be met, the recursion doesn't stop.

Answer (score 0):

So I've got the final answer; points.Count should be <= 1 in the first IF statement. Similarly, any code resembling list[index] = left[leftindex] (or something like this) should be changed into list.add(left[leftindex])

Full code below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> test = new List<int>();

            List<int> answer = new List<int>();

            test.Add(1);
            test.Add(6);
            test.Add(-2);
            test.Add(323);
            test.Add(32);
            test.Add(-32);
            test.Add(23);
            test.Add(3);
            test.Add(123);
            test.Add(5);

            answer = MSort(test);

            Console.WriteLine(answer);

            for (int i = 0; i < answer.Count; i++) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(answer[i]);
            }

        }
        public static List<int> MSort(List<int> points)
        {
            List<int> left, right;
            List<int> result = new List<int>(points.Count);

            if (points.Count <= 1) { return points; }

            int midpoint = points.Count / 2;

            left = new List<int>(midpoint);

            if ((points.Count % 2) == 0)
            {
                right = new List<int>(midpoint);
            }
            else { right = new List<int>(midpoint + 1); }

            for (int i = 0; i < midpoint; i++)
            {
                left.Add(points[i]);
            }

            for (int j = midpoint; j < points.Count; j++)
            {
                right.Add(points[j]);
            }

            left = MSort(left);
            right = MSort(right);

            result = Merge(left, right);
            return result;

        }

        public static List<int> Merge(List<int> left, List<int> right)
        {
            int length = left.Count + right.Count;

            List<int> result = new List<int>(length);

            int leftIndex, rightIndex, resultIndex;
            leftIndex = rightIndex = resultIndex = 0;

            while ((leftIndex < left.Count) || (rightIndex < right.Count))
            {
                if ((leftIndex < left.Count) && (rightIndex < right.Count))
                {
                    if (left[leftIndex] <= right[rightIndex])
                    {
                        result.Add(left[leftIndex]);
                        leftIndex++;
                        resultIndex++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result.Add(right[rightIndex]);
                        rightIndex++;
                        resultIndex++;
                    }
                }
                else if (leftIndex < left.Count)
                {
                    result.Add(left[leftIndex]);
                    leftIndex++;
                    resultIndex++;
                }
                else if (rightIndex < right.Count)
                {
                    result.Add(right[rightIndex]);
                    rightIndex++;
                    resultIndex++;
                }
            }
            return result;
```

The output is correct; it outputs negative numbers first then positive numbers.